# Android Studio: Using support v4 library

Tags: android, gradle

I need some classes from the v4 support library, under Android Studio 0.5.9, like `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, but i cannot access them.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    provided files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

I tried to add the line: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'`, but no effect.
After I copied the .jar file to the libs folder, and added the line: `provided files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`, but did not worked. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you remember to press the `gradle sync` button? Also, when using `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+` line, you don't need the jar.

Comment: I did. And shows up in the Project Structure correctly.

Comment: There may be a problem with the gradle sync: Error:exception during working with external system:

Comment: Having both "compile" and "provided" for the support library seems odd to me. I would use one or the other. compile means the library needs to be included into your apk while provided means it is needed to compile the project but not to be included.

Comment: The compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+' line worked after a complete reinstall from the ground.